# ConstraintLayout not changing to landscape

Tags: android, kotlin, android-constraintlayout

I am a begginer in android. So I created an small android app using ConstraintLayout, just to test. But, everytime I click on the button to change the orientation of the screen on the emulator, it´s not changing, it continues the same. As far as I remember, with linear layout, the orientation change, but it breaks the layout if you not handle well with it. But with ConstraintLayout, it always continue the same

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".view.MainActivity">
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars[0]"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="120dp" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="120dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="120dp" android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
            android:layout_marginBottom="497dp" app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"/>

    <TextView
            android:text="Get Rewarded with this"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/textView" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp" android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="33dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light" android:lineSpacingMultiplier="40"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="40sp"
            android:textSize="32dp"`enter code here`
            android:layout_marginBottom="378dp" app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Constraintlayout will handle it automatically for your simple layout.

Comment: But on my simple app, it's not working properly

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can just make individual layout for landscape view. That way:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Adij.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmIva.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBzCX.png

Comment: It does not change normally like a linear layout?